# How can I keep const-correctness and RAII?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, raii, weak-ptr

I have situation similar to included:

```
class A
{
    public:
        A(shared_ptr<B>);
}

class B : public enable_shared_from_this<B>
{
    const shared_ptr<A> a;
}
```

I can't have `shared_ptr` to `B` before construction, so before `a` is initialized. So, I need to initialize my constant field after construction (I think it denies RAII), or just construct it later (so it can't be const, so it denies const-correctness, and also looks like not-too-consistent with RAII).

It looks like propably common situation. Is there any the cleanest way to handle this? How would you do this?

Comment: This is the reason I don't use std::shared_ptr extensively.

Comment: Why do you have a const member?

Comment: @Mehrdad I made mistake writing post: In my code, `a` is public. But you're right, you and Angrew: I don't need const fields if I have this field private and public getter. And I can keep RAII, using friend factory to initialize my fields after construction's call.

Comment: IMHO the cyclic dependency between `A` and `B` indicates that there should be another solution with less coupling between these two types.

Comment: @Nobody Right, A should get weak_ptr in constructor, I forgot about cycles. I'm beginning with smart pointers.

Comment: I don't even talk about the smart pointers and I think a `std::weak_ptr` won't solve the problem that I am talking about: the code dependencies that seem wrong. Without seeing the actual code there is not much more that I can say about this.

Comment: @KrzysztofStanisławek: I can't think of a single situation in which making a field `const` is a good idea. I'd say remove the constness. (Circular references are another issue.)

Comment: @Nobody
You're right. I want to pass reference to `B` to constructor of `A`, because `A` needs to update some global statistics, and to have access to some global configuration. But I can separate this data into some object, which can be field of `B` and won't need reference to `B`.
I don't know why I didn't think about it before. It looks like cyclic dependencies are always bad, but it's usually possible to avoid them. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I would solve this by not having `const` members, plain and simple. They are generally much more trouble than they're worth (they make the class non-assignable, not even move-assignable, for example).

`a` is private, so only the class itself can access it. Thus it should be enough to document "`a` should never be modified after being initialised!!!". If you fear that won't be enough (or the class has `friend`s outside your control), you can make this even more obvious like this:

```
class B : public enable_shared_from_this<B>
{
  const std::shared_ptr<A>& a() { return _use_this_ONLY_for_initialising_a; }

  std::shared_ptr<A> _use_this_ONLY_for_initialising_a;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Such a situation is a good indicator to refactor your code. Think about whether `B` should actually inhert from `A` or be a member of `A` before finding a way around this problem...

.. because it is probably going to be to remove the constness of your object - and probably not use shared_ptr (you have a cyclical reference there, so ref-counting alone will never be able to destroy your objects!).

Comment: `A` definitely shouldn't inherit. `A` is some small component strongly related with `B`, which I distribute to some parts of GUI to separate interface.
I think I'll just give up with `const`, use getter to access field (in my code `a` is `public`) and factory to build object (to be consistent with RAII).
About cyclic dependence - I think `A` should take `weak_ptr`, it's my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

If `A` doesn't actually keep a copy of the `shared_ptr<B>` you pass it (just uses the `B` briefly) then you can make this work (see below) but:

1. If `A` doesn't keep a reference to the `B` then it could just take a `B&` or `B*` argument, not a `shared_ptr<B>`, so you should change the design.
2. If `A` does keep a reference then you're going to have a circular reference, so you should change the design.

This works, but is really, really horrible and would be easy to introduce bugs, and is generally a bad idea, I probably shouldn't even be showing it, just change your design to avoid circular dependencies:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class B;

class A
{
public:
  A(std::shared_ptr<B> b);
};


class B : public std::enable_shared_from_this<B>
{

  // return a shared_ptr<B> that owns `this` but with a
  // null deleter. This does not share ownership with
  // the result of shared_from_this(), but is usable
  // in the B::B constructor.
  std::shared_ptr<B> non_owning_shared_from_this()
  {
    struct null_deleter {
      void operator()(void*) const { }
    };

    return std::shared_ptr<B>(this, null_deleter());
  }

public:
  B(int id)
  : m_id(id), a(std::make_shared<A>(non_owning_shared_from_this()))
  { }

  int id() const { return m_id; }

private:
  int m_id;
  const std::shared_ptr<A> a;
};

A::A(std::shared_ptr<B> b)
{
  std::cout << b->id() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  auto b = std::make_shared<B>(42);
}
```